# jQuery select all anchors that have a certain class

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to access all anchors in the page that has a certain class using jQuery

*For example. access all anchors that have class "bold"*

I tried

```
$('.bold');
```

But I only need to select the anchors, can you please help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're certainly not Tom Cruise or Brad Pitt, but can you please accept the answer if it is right :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following selector:

```
$('a.bold');
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't `$('a.bold');` be what you need?

Comment: @Scott how is what you said different from my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I guess my eyesight is going. :)